# Исправить надпись "Добавить комментарий"

Tags: предложение, дизайн

Вот есть такая картинка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и либо мне кажется, либо кнопка "Добавить комментарий" немного сдвинута. И возможно имеет смысл сделать надпись с большой буквы? Красная линия моя если что))) Это я для наглядности нарисовал :D

Comment: Оно и по вертикали так себе стоит, причём в обоих случаях - и если вопрос отредактирован, и если нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy, значит меня не глючит и оно всем так выглядит)

Comment: и я это скопировал из под своего ответа, но рядом с вопросом наверное так же выглядит

Comment: Такое надо на MSE постить. Но сомневаюсь, что предложение будет воспринято позитивно.